# Is there a way to do spell check on the data in the database?

Tags: php, spell-checking

I have a lot of user generated content, and it is often poorly written, and sometimes I like to fix the errors to make the writing better. The problem is that my spelling is pretty bad too :)

Is there a programatic way to detect errors that get into the database? Maybe right before they are put in the db? Or even once they are in there?

I am using PHP so any solutions with php would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [pspell](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php) - it might help.